# How to automatically adjust divs as per the content inside each div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to create number of boxes using div (each div having different number of contents) and each 2 div should be in a row.
But the problem is if one div has more content then it gets bigger than the other one. This creates a space below the other div and the next div comes after that.[image: instead of the marked white space div should come there]

i am using angular js ng-repeat for creating all the divs.
The code i used is as below:

```
<div id="form" ng-controller="JobApplicationFormController">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">

        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" ng-repeat="x in categorylist" style="margin-bottom:10px">
            <div class="card1">

                <div class="container1">
                    <div style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding: 5px;margin-left: -16px;margin-right: -16px;font-size:20px !important;color:black">
                        <img src="~/Images/form.ico" style="height:50px" /> <b>{{x.categoryName}}</b>
                    </div>

                    <div ng-repeat="y in formlist" ng-if="y.categoryId==x.id" id="{{y.id}}" onclick="return popitup('../../Applications/Form/' + this.id)" class="formlist" title="click to upload" style="cursor:pointer;padding: 5px;margin-left: -16px;margin-right: -16px;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">

                        <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none" ng-if="y.status=='Completed'" ><img src="~/Images/green_circle.png" style="height:15px" />&nbsp;<font color="green"> {{y.formName}} </font></a>
                        <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none" ng-if="y.status!='Completed'" ><img src="~/Images/red_circle.png" style="height:15px" />&nbsp;<font color="red"> {{y.formName}} </font> </a>
                        </div>


                </div>
            </div>

            </div>
    </div>
```

I've tried this[[Auto adjusting div based on inside content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507334/auto-adjusting-div-based-on-inside-content]) for reference but it doesn't works properly. there is overflow of content.

Edit1: I did try this [[CSS-only masonry layout but with elements ordered horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377343/css-only-masonry-layout-but-with-elements-ordered-horizontally]) already but it is not getting me near to anywhere what I want to achieve. the div part is what is causing a lot of trouble.

Comment: remove <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12"> and tell me if it works

Comment: nope..didn't work

Comment: could you post code of page after it's rendered?

Comment: if every box has the same width, you can try a solution with flexboxes (`display: flex;`), like this example of [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_flex-wrap_wrap)

Comment: @NoOorZ24  I'm unable to send the code as it exceeds the character limit . is there any other method please suggest ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2otpzbgt/1/